# SQL Server stored procedure throws error Must declare the scalar variable ' '

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, exec

I have tried `exec proc ...` in many ways but every time a new error occurs.

The procedure is created without errors but the problem is when i try to execute it.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PRC1(@Card_code bigint, @Months dateTIME OUT,@Charge 
decimal(10,2))
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE CRS CURSOR
FOR 

SELECT 0.01*t.charge AS 
firstTENDAYS,cc.Card_code,datepart(MONTH,t.Trans_time_date) AS NMONTH
from TRANSSACTION t join CREDIT_CARD cc on t.Card_code=cc.Card_code
where datepart(day,t.trans_time_date) between 0 and 10  and 
@Card_code=CONVERT(int,cc.Card_code ) and 
@MonthS=datepart(MONTH,t.Trans_time_date) and
@Charge=t.Charge


SELECT 0.03*t.charge AS 
thirdTENDAYS,cc.Card_code,datepart(MONTH,t.Trans_time_date) AS NMONTH
from TRANSSACTION t join CREDIT_CARD cc on t.Card_code=cc.Card_code
where datepart(day,t.trans_time_date) between 21 and 31  and
@Card_code=CONVERT(int,cc.Card_code )and 
@Months=datepart(MONTH,t.Trans_time_date) and 
@Charge=t.Charge


open CRS
FETCH NEXT FROM CRS
INTO @Card_code,@Months,@Charge

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
print @Card_code
print @Months
print @Charge
FETCH NEXT FROM CRS
INTO @Card_code,@Months,@Charge
END
CLOSE CRS DEALLOCATE CRS END

EXEC PRC1 @Card_code,Months,@Charge
```

When I execute it,the below error occurs:
Must declare the scalar variable "@Card_code".

Comment: If the problem is with how you are trying to execute it you should also show that code. Also what is the full error message? What is the name of the scalar variable it wants you to declare?

Comment: Show us the code you use to execute the proc when you get the error in the subject line.

Comment: Go read the documentation about cursors first. If you open one, you should also close one. And declare should be followed by deallocate. Simple searching will find many examples of proper cursor usage. Start learning. Next, your cursor does nothing useful, so this is an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). So start over. What is the goal of your procedure? And give your procedure a useful name - not gibberish!

Answer (score 1):

You did not declare the variables you are passing in following your `exec` statement. When you execute a stored proc you need to pass in the parameters required in the stored proc definition with either literal values or a variable. Your stored proc definition has 3 parameters:

1. `@Card_code bigint`
2. `@Months dateTIME OUT`
3. `@Charge decimal(10,2)`

When you execute the stored proc, you need to supply the requested parameters following your exec statement. Since parameter 3 is an input and output parameter and is being returned to the caller, you need to pass in a variable you declared to store the result. For parameter 1 and 3, which are only input parameters, you can supply the stored proc with a constant value or a variable you declared that stores a value.

```
DECLARE @myCardCode BIGINT = 999;
DECLARE @monthsReturned DATETIME = getDate();
EXEC PRC1 @myCardCode, @monthsReturned, 100.00 --parameter 1 passed in as variable, parameter 2 is a variable to store the output result, parameter 3 is a constant value
```